# ApacheWicket Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClas

Tags: spring, spring-boot, wicket

I am following Spring Boot + Apache Wicket tutorials: https://udemy.com/course/starting-with-apache-wicket-version-9x/learn/lecture/33750684#overview and have below code.

When I add below line to HomePage.java code started giving me below error

```
@SpringBean
private MongoDBService mongoDBService;
```

HomePage.java

```
import app.services.MongoDBService;
import app.web.pages.BasePage;
import com.giffing.wicket.spring.boot.context.scan.WicketHomePage;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;
import org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringBean;
import org.wicketstuff.annotation.mount.MountPath;

@WicketHomePage
@MountPath(value = "home", alt = {"home2"})
@Slf4j
public class HomePage extends BasePage {
    @SpringBean
    private MongoDBService mongoDBService;

    public HomePage() {
        Label label = new Label("label", "My custom page title from Wicket! "+mongoDBService.getRepo().count());
        add(label);
    }
}
```

BasePage.java

```
public abstract class BasePage extends WebPage {

    public BasePage(PageParameters params){
        super(params);
        Injector.get().inject(this);
        initPage();
    }

    public BasePage(){
        Injector.get().inject(this);
        initPage();
    }

    private void initPage(){
    }


    @Override
    public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
        super.renderHead(response);

        response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(getApplication().getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getJQueryReference()));
        response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forReference(getApplication().getJavaScriptLibrarySettings().getWicketAjaxReference()));

        response.render(JavaScriptHeaderItem.forUrl("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"));
        response.render(CssHeaderItem.forUrl("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"));
    }
}
```

MongoDBService.java

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class MongoDBService {

    @Autowired
    @Getter
    private TodoMongoDBRepository repo;

    @PostConstruct
    void setup() {
        log.info("+++ MongoDB database is starting ...");
        repo.deleteAll();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++) {
            Todo todo = new Todo();
            todo.setTitle("Todo number " + i);
            todo.setBody("Body number " + i);
            addToItems(todo);
        }
    }

    public List<Todo> getAllItems() {
        return StreamSupport.stream(repo.findAll().spliterator(), false)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public void addToItems(Todo todo) {
        repo.save(todo);
    }

    public void removeItems(List<Todo> items) {
        repo.deleteAll(items);
    }
}
```

HomePage.java

```
@WicketHomePage
@MountPath(value = "home", alt = {"home2"})
@Slf4j
public class HomePage extends BasePage {
    @SpringBean
    private MongoDBService mongoDBService;

    public HomePage() {
        Label label = new Label("label", "My custom page title from Wicket! "+mongoDBService.getRepo().count());
        add(label);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Caused by: net.sf.cglib.core.CodeGenerationException: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException-->Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @58c1670b
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(ReflectUtils.java:464) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:339) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:96) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData$3.apply(AbstractClassGenerator.java:94) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache$2.call(LoadingCache.java:54) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.createEntry(LoadingCache.java:61) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.internal.LoadingCache.get(LoadingCache.java:34) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator$ClassLoaderData.get(AbstractClassGenerator.java:119) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:294) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.create(KeyFactory.java:221) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:174) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory.create(KeyFactory.java:153) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.<clinit>(Enhancer.java:73) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    ... 72 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InaccessibleObjectException: Unable to make protected final java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain) throws java.lang.ClassFormatError accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.lang" to unnamed module @58c1670b
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:354) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkCanSetAccessible(AccessibleObject.java:297) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.checkCanSetAccessible(Method.java:199) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.setAccessible(Method.java:193) ~[na:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1.run(ReflectUtils.java:61) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.<clinit>(ReflectUtils.java:52) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.KeyFactory$Generator.generateClass(KeyFactory.java:243) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.generate(AbstractClassGenerator.java:332) ~[cglib-3.3.0.jar:na]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Hi, it looks more a JPMS related problem. I guess you are using Java modules in your project. How do you run your code?

Comment: No its not module, its a single App only, using InteliJ to run the code

Answer (score 0):

In you `Run configuration` you need to go to `Modify options` and check `Do not use --module-path option`

[image]